# Git's "log" command returned a hash for a specific file that "show" then rejected

Tags: git

I asked Git for all the hashes (commits) that changed a particular file with `log`. I got a list with 6 hashes.

When I then use `show` on those hashes it works fine for the first 5, but for the last one (the oldest) I get an error:

```
fatal: Path [filename} exists on disk, but not in {hash}.
```

How can that be?!

The file in question was never renamed, and it was part of the project from the very start because it is the principal file. I have commited six times, so I expected a list with 6 items, and that's what I got.

Answer (score 0):

With the commit in question the file was deleted.

My only excuse is that this was an accident, and therefore I did not expect it.